# Ampersand Symbol Converted to And String in MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have a CSV with a string "Writing Concepts & Skills" but, when I run the below code the "ampersand symbol" is converted to an "and" string. Why is that happening and how can I avoid that?

```
load data local infile '~/Grade\ Levels.csv'
into table test_codes
fields terminated by ',' enclosed by '"'
lines terminated by '\r\n';
```

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen thanks for the reply! So you're suggesting "Writing Concepts &amp; Skills"?

Comment: are there any triggers on the table that could be doing this?

Comment: @JanR nope, no triggers in the table.

Comment: that seems weird, as far as I know mysql would not be changing that by itself

Comment: How are you viewing the csv? Is it definitely `&` in unicode or whatever the encoding is? This is odd as it should be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this stage with no further information this seems quite odd.

But most times when it is an issue with other things like xml or if you are doing this through php etc.

If you replace `&` with `&amp;` that could work.